# ggplot and dplyr and column name as string

Tags: r, string, ggplot2, dplyr

I would like to process data frame through `dplyr` and `ggplot` using column names in form of string. Here is my code

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
my_df <- data.frame(var_1 = sample(c('a', 'b', 'c'), 1000, replace = TRUE),
                    var_2 = sample(c('d', 'e', 'f'), 1000, replace = TRUE))

name_list = c('var_1', 'var_2')

for(el in name_list){
  pdf(paste(el, '.pdf', sep =''))
    test <- my_df %>% group_by(el) %>% summarize(count = n())
    ggplot(data = test, aes(x = el, y = count)) + geom_bar(stat='identity')
  dev.off()
}
```

The above code obviously does not work. So I tried different things like `UQ` and `as.name`. `UQ` creates column with extra quotes and ggplot does not understand it with `aes_string`. Any suggestions?

I can use `for (el in names(my_df))` with filtering, but would prefer to work with strings.

**UPDATE**
Here are detailed messages/errors that I got:

```
for(el in name_list){
  pdf(paste(el, '.pdf', sep =''))
    test <- my_df %>% group_by(!!el) %>% summarize(count = n())
    ggplot(data = test, aes_string(x = el, y = 'count')) + geom_bar(stat='identity')
  dev.off()
}
```

The above code generate empty files.

```
for(el in name_list){
  pdf(paste(el, '.pdf', sep =''))
    test <- my_df %>% group_by(UQ(el)) %>% summarize(count = n())
    ggplot(data = test, aes_string(x = el, y = 'count')) + geom_bar(stat='identity')
  dev.off()
}
```

The above code also generates empty files

```
for(el in name_list){
  pdf(paste(el, '.pdf', sep =''))
    test <- my_df %>% group_by(as.name(el)) %>% summarize(count = n())
    ggplot(data = test, aes_string(x = el, y = 'count')) + geom_bar(stat='identity')
  dev.off()
}
```

produces

```
Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Column `as.name(el)` is of unsupported type symbol
```

Comment: Related: (dplyr) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45442513/dplyr-0-7-specify-grouping-variable-as-string (ggplot) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15458526/r-pass-variable-column-indices-to-ggplot2

Comment: Show your attempts with `UQ` and `aes_string`. Give the error messages you got. Otherwise this each part of this is just a duplicate of a simpler question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to `UQ` (or `!!`) the name/symbol. For example

```
for(el in name_list){
  pdf(paste(el, '.pdf', sep =''))
  test <- my_df %>% group_by(UQ(as.name(el))) %>% summarize(count = n())
  print(ggplot(data = test, aes_string(x = el, y = 'count')) + geom_bar(stat='identity'))
  dev.off()
}
```

Comment: Oh. You need to print() the ggplot object inside a loop with this method. Didn't think about that problem because I missed that part.

Answer (score 2):

I made two changes to your code:

1. To "group by" variable in `dplyr` use `group_by_` instead of `group_by`;
2. To call variable in `ggplot2` use `aes_string` or `get(variable)`;

I also added minor changes (e.g. `ggsave` to save plots).

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
my_df <- data.frame(var_1 = sample(c('a', 'b', 'c'), 1000, replace = TRUE),
                    var_2 = sample(c('d', 'e', 'f'), 1000, replace = TRUE))

name_list = c('var_1', 'var_2')

for(el in name_list){
    p <- my_df %>% 
         group_by_(el) %>% 
         summarize(count = n()) %>%
         ggplot(aes(x = get(el), y = count)) +
             geom_bar(stat = "identity")
    ggsave(paste0(el, ".pdf"), p)
}
```

Comment: `ggsave` made all the difference, but without `ggsave` it does not work

Comment: The reason `ggsave` is needed for this to work is that `get()` is evaluated lazily. You need `ggsave` inside the loop to make sure `get()` pulls the correct string. I found that if I use `aes_string` instead of `get()` then things are fine. I.e.: `ggplot(aes_string(x = el, y = "count")) ...`